# select * group by distinct columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table data as follows:

`Id      c1  c2
8802    1   1
8802    3   1
8802    3   2
8802    4   1`

How do I write a query to fetch all columns, but have a unique (id,c1). It does not matter what the value in c2 is

My final output would look like this

`Id      c1  c2
2202    1   1
2202    3   (1 or 2 does not matter) 
2202    4   1`

I have 10+ columns in the table and all the columns need to be displayed. To use the group by clause I need to provide a select clause with those specific column names and I don't get the output I desire

`select Id, c1 from table group by (Id, c1)` will give a listing of just `Id,c1`.

How do I get all columns?

Thanks!

Comment: `Select ID, C1, max(C2) or Min(C2) FROM table Group by (ID, C1)`  use max or min if it really doesn't matter.  or `LISTAGG(C2, ', ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C2)` if you want both values in a comma separated list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a group by, you would want to use aggregration with it.  You may not care which value of C2 is returned; but the System needs to know which one you want.

So:

```
SELECT ID, C1, max(C2) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY ID, C1
```

OR use a window function such as LISTAGG to combine all values into a comma separated list

```
SELECT ID, C1, LISTAGG(C2, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C2)` 
FROM table
GROUP BY ID, C1
```

Or use a CTE and a window function to assign a row number and limit to just the 1st record of each grouping.  Given the other columns and a presumed desire for related values to the same C2 value; this seems like the best approach.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT A.*, Row_number() over (partition by ID, C1 ORDER BY C2) RN
FROM table A)
SELEC *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: thanks xQbert for the response, but I need a select * as I have 10+ columns and I dont want to specify all the column names in the group by clause.. the existing output that i have is that of a CTE and I need to filter it to the above criteria...

Comment: 3rd option should work fine then.   Just include the window/analytical function `row_number()` in the base CTE and then filter by it.  or build a CTE on the CTE...   Provide sample data in a rextester.com or sqlfiddle.com; we'll show it working!

Comment: It took me while to figure out how to use CTE on a CTE but I now have the desired output. Honestly, I haven't ever used the syntax over (partition by..). So, I have some learning to do right now, but thanks much for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregation function:

```
select id, c1, min(c2) as c2
from t
group by id, c1;
```

You want one row per distinct value of `id`/`c1`.  Hence, those should be in the `group by`.  If you want other columns, they should be the arguments to aggregation functions.

You can use window functions to get a bunch of columns:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id, c1 order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, could you show me an implementation with select *, as I need all the columns (10+)?